# SyntaxError: invalid syntax при старте бота на хостинге

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

Всех приветствую, написал бота на python (aiogram), при запуске бота на ПК все работает хорошо, после того как залил бота на хостинг, начала появляться ошибка, и не появляются reply кнопки
[image: Ошибка]

Пробовал преобразовывать тип данных ошибка остаётся.
Прошу что нибудь подсказать

Comment: Логичный вопрос — какая версия python на хостинге?

Comment: match появился в Python 3.10, скорее всего на хостинге запускаете более старой версией Python.

Comment: версия 3.8.10, как ее можно обновить? или проще будет использовать switch?

Comment: Проблема была в версии python, обновил, всем спасибо